# read data skipping the column name in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have some unstructured data and need to perform some munging over it.
**university_towns.txt**:

```
Alabama[edit]
Auburn (Auburn University)[1]
Florence (University of North Alabama)
Jacksonville (Jacksonville State University)[2]
Livingston (University of West Alabama)[2]
Montevallo (University of Montevallo)[2]
Troy (Troy University)[2]
```

When I read this file using pd.read_table I got pandas name the column I need by the first line ('Alabama[edit]').

```
def get_list_of_university_towns():
    df = pd.read_table('university_towns.txt')
    df = df.reset_index()
    return list(df)
> ['index', 'Alabama[edit]']
```

How can I reset this 'automatic naming' so my both columns are custom-named and **I don't lose first string ('Alabama[edit]')**?

I think there might be a certain argument passed to [read_table](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/generated/pandas.read_table.html), but I am not sure which one.

Comment: You can use `pd.read_table('university_towns.txt', header=None)`

Comment: Awesome. I had tried both 0 and 1 but `None` did the trick !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in several ways.

For example:

You can define the column names when you use pd.read_table:

**col**=["Cities"]

df=pd.read_table("D:\datos\university_towns.txt.txt", **names=col**)

Comment: It works too, but `header=None` works better. Thanks

Comment: sure!!! I assumed taht you want to named you data columns but I was wrong